# Algorithm to Compute Diagonal Elements of the Inverse of a Penta-diagonal Matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms, inverse

Given a symmetric penta-diagonal matrix A

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    c_{1}       & b_{1} & a_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    b_{1}       & c_{2} & b_{2} & a_{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
    a_{1}      & b_{2} & c_{3} & b_{3} & a_{3} & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    0 & \cdots & a_{L-3} & b_{L-2} & c_{L-1} & b_{L-1} \\
    0 & \cdots & 0 & a_{L-2} & b_{L-1} & c_{L}
\end{bmatrix}$,

where $c_{i}$,$b_{i}$ and $a_{i}$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ or $ \mathbb{C}$.  The matrix is also considered to be invertable as $G A = I$ then $G = A^{-1}$ which reads

$G = \begin{bmatrix}
    G_{11}       & G_{12} & G_{13} & \dots & G_{1L} \\
    G_{21}       & G_{22} & G_{23} & \dots & G_{2L} \\
    \vdots \\
    G_{L1}       & G_{L2} & G_{L3} & \dots & G_{LL}
\end{bmatrix}$.

My questions is:  *is there an efficient algorithm to compute just the diagonal elements* $G_{i,i}$?

I know how to do it efficiently for a tri-diagonal matrix in $O(N)$ steps, but I'm unsure if such speedup is possible for the penta-diagonal case.

Comment: [This](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2015/232456/) ?

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply. I'm a bit unfamiliar with the mapping they are performing in this paper. Their idea is to take penta-diagonal matrix and transform it to a linear system of equation that one can easily solve. How do you get the inverse? I feel this should be obvious but it is not clear to be atm.

Comment: @P.Siehr forgot to tag

Comment: @P.Siehr Maybe more details will help. My goal is to solve the following system of ODEs: $ \frac{d y_{i}}{d \omega} = G(\omega)_{i,i}$ for $i = 1,2,...L$. Does recasting this to a linear system system of equations for penta-diagonal matrix makes sense?